# interact with iframe on Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js

nuxt: 2.0.0
vue: 2.6.10
Mac OS: 10.14

I have an application on Nuxt.js, and also have App.vue on Vue.js.
I built App.vue to index.html, js and css, and tried embed built index.html to my application on Nuxt.js but it never work.
I have no idea with What the part is not working is App.vue's @click event.

App.vue has svg image and the image is separated to clickable parts.
When I click the clickable part, clicked part will be changed the color which is the sign of a click.

I built that and put Nuxt.js's static folder, and embed with iframe by specifying the static folder's index.html src.

This iframe only works to show the svg image but click event and changing color are never working.

So many references and websites I searched for the solution and often saw `.postMessage` to interact between iframe and parent, but it's never sending my console the messages.

Again I say for confirmation, iframe's svg image is correctly showed but only click event part is not working.

A code below is the code which was embedded App.vue, that is the iframe's parent

```
<template lang='pug'>
v-card(flat, color='transparent')
  v-layout(row, wrap, align-center, justify-center)
    v-flex(xs12, sm8, md4)
      div.headline.font-weight-black.accent--text {{ getDoubleDigestNumber(questionNumber) }}
      p.font-weight-bold.py-0(v-if='question.attributes.body') {{ question.attributes.body }}
      p.grey--text.py-0(v-if='question.attributes.note') {{ question.attributes.note }}
  v-layout(row, wrap, align-center, justify-center)
    v-flex.text-xs-center(xs12, sm8, md4)
      div#dermatome-map-container
        iframe#dermatome-map(ref='dermatome', v-bind:src='dermatomeMapUrl', frameborder="0")
      v-btn(
        block,
        color='primary',
        v-on:click='onClickNext') {{ $t('word.next') }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'QuestionnairePageQuestionDecimal',
  props: [
    'question',
    'questionNumber'
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      form: { isLoading: false }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dermatomeMapUrl() {
      return '/dermatome/index.html'
    }
  },
  mouted() {
    window.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg.data)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onClickNext() {
      this.$EventBus.$emit('onClickNext', { question_id: this.question, form: this.form })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue is too longer to write here, so just inside

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: [
    'clickable',
    'selectedCategories'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      COLOR_STROKE: '#353535',
      COLOR_C: '#ED6C63',
      COLOR_L: '#97CD76',
      COLOR_S: '#42AFE3',
      COLOR_T: '#FCE473',
      COLOR_C_SELECTED: 'url(#selectedC)',
      COLOR_L_SELECTED: 'url(#selectedL)',
      COLOR_S_SELECTED: 'url(#selectedS)',
      COLOR_T_SELECTED: 'url(#selectedT)',
      categoriesSelection: {
        c1: false,
        c2: false,
        c3: false,
        c4: false,
        c5: false,
        c6: false,
        c7: false,
        c8: false,
        l1: false,
        l2: false,
        l3: false,
        l4: false,
        l5: false,
        s1: false,
        s2: false,
        s3: false,
        s4: false,
        s5: false,
        t1: false,
        t2: false,
        t3: false,
        t4: false,
        t5: false,
        t6: false,
        t7: false,
        t8: false,
        t9: false,
        t10: false,
        t11: false,
        t12: false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.makeContainerSquare()
    if (this.selectedCategories) {
      this.selectedCategories.forEach((selectedCategory) => {
        this.categoriesSelection[selectedCategory] = true
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeContainerSquare () {
      if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
        let style = ''
        style += `width:${window.innerWidth}px;`
        style += `height:${window.innerWidth}px;`
        style += `margin-top:${(window.innerHeight - window.innerWidth) / 2}px;`
        this.$refs.container.setAttribute('style', style)
      } else {
        let style = ''
        style += `width:${window.innerHeight}px;`
        style += `height:${window.innerHeight}px;`
        style += `margin-left:${(window.innerHeight - window.innerHeight) / 2}px;`
        this.$refs.container.setAttribute('style', style)
      }
    },
    onClickCategory (categories) {
      if (!this.clickable) {
        return
      }
      categories.forEach((category) => {
        this.categoriesSelection[category] = !this.categoriesSelection[category]
      })
      categories.forEach((category) => {
        window.parent.postMessage({
          'name': category,
          'applicable': this.categoriesSelection[category]
        }, '/')
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang='stylus'>
svg.dermatome {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I want you teach me how the click event in an iframe works.